# window.setInterval unpredictability in New Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval, microsoft-edge

I'm developing an app that relies on window.setInterval.  I'm having an issue with the new Chromium based Edge browser that doesnt seem to happen with any other browser I've tested (Chrome, FF)

I noticed some strange behavior in the app seemingly connected to an AngularJS $interval method.
So I began testing the native JS window.setInterval to see if the issue was AngularJS or the underlying native JS.
The issue occurs with the native JS methods as well.

To boil this down the the simplest repeatable example possible, I created two codePen's [one with AngularJS](https://codepen.io/zachsteffens/pen/LYxPvbo) and [one without](https://codepen.io/zachsteffens/pen/oNBvPov)

To test the codepen open a dev tools window and after the first minute, console logs will output the elapsed time between calls to the interval callback function.

The purpose of this code is to output the time between calls to the setInterval callback function.

```
window.setInterval((event) => {
  const lastTime = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("lastTime"));
  const thisTime = new Date();
  if (lastTime) {
    const timeDiff = thisTime.getTime() - Date.parse(lastTime);
    console.log("time: " + timeDiff.toString());
  }
  window.sessionStorage.setItem("lastTime", JSON.stringify(thisTime));
}, 30000);
```

This code should output "time: 30000" or something within a few ms of 30000.
In Edge, this time becomes erratic and has gone as high as 81999 but most often when it malfunctions, it reports within a few ms of 60000.

When I inject this code into the landing page of my web app the timer begins to malfunction after 5 to 10 iterations.   These aren't slight anomalies,  they are off by a factor of 2.  Starting at 30 seconds, and then moving to 60 seconds

In the included code pens, they might function fine, or they might malfunction after a short or long period of time. I've had 2 co-workers running them as well and they almost all fail eventually. Sometimes get off by a factor of 2 (going to 60 seconds) and recovering back to to 30s, or staying at 60 seconds for hours. I've been refreshing the pages every few hours to try to reset things to see if I can determine a pattern but I can't.  Rarely they work fine for the duration, most often they malfunction and get stuck at 60000ms.

Comment: setInterval is never accurate

Comment: Also there's no reason to parse the time as a Date; you're saving a numeric timestamp. You don't need `JSON.stringify()` either.

Comment: It's typically accurate enough, and not off by a factor of 2 when the interval is 30s.  This example was for illustrative purposes. In my actual app, the interval is 300 seconds, but sometimes Edge runs the interval at 500s.  I know interval is not accurate to the ms but it should be good enough to handle longer intervals within an acceptable tolerance.

Comment: Note that when a browser tab is not active, modern browsers can and do slow down interval timers.

Comment: That is very weird indeed, but setInterval is not reliable especially if you're expecting it to run forever. My suggestion is doing this same thing with a recursive setTimeout, I usually go around a lot of weird setInterval issues by using recursive time outs instead.

Comment: @Pointy, the code was a port from my app where the date object is a moment.js object where Stringify is necessary...

Comment: All `JSON.stringify()` will do is convert the value to a string, which will be the simple numeric timestamp. It's not necessary.

Comment: @pointy, In my original code, the time is a moment object, so unless i want session storage to store "[object Object]" it has to be converted to a string.  It was an oversight in the code port that has no functional relevance to the question I asked...

Comment: Well the main thing is to find out why the timer is getting off. What is the *actual* interval? 300ms? If so, that's a completely different issue than 30000ms. The browser is likely to slow down the page if it loses focus, or for any other reason really.

Comment: Also, to continue in my pedantic mode, just save `.getTime()` instead of the overhead of `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: The interval is 30000ms (30 seconds).  And the code is to illustrate the underlying problem, not to stand up to pointless scrutiny on SO.  I'm dealing with an autologout of customers from an enterprise website, I wasn't all that focused on writing perfect code when in a rush to determine what seems to be a ludicrous issue with Edge's handling of setInterval.

Comment: Honestly I've never encountered the problem, and my auto-logout code works with `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`, so that my code can itself adjust the interval by examining the actual elapsed time. That is, you set a timeout, and in the timeout handler you check the *actual* elapsed time, and then adjust the next interval accordingly.

Comment: ^ this ensures that the timeout/interval is freshly created, and not the hot mess that usually bugs out that is called setInterval.

Comment: I made some tests with your native JS codepen. In my test results, I didn't find the issue in Edge but found the issue in Chrome. In Edge, the outputs in console are all around 30000 but in Chrome there're outputs around 60000. My Edge version is 89.0.774.57 and Chrome version is 89.0.4389.90. I have several tabs opened in Chrome but only one tab opened in Edge, don't know if this has any influence.